# Can Not Get Firebase Notifications Working for Web App

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to set up Firebase push notifications except I can't seem to get the notifications to work on a web app. Are these limited to Android and iPhone? I followed their guide on how to set it up with a JavaScript client. Here's my code:

index.html

```
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then((registration) => {
          console.log('Service worker installed.');
          window.swRegistration = registration;
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>
```

service-worker.js

```
'use strict';
importScripts('./build/sw-toolbox.js');
importScripts('./assets/js/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('./assets/js/firebase-messaging.js');

self.toolbox.options.cache = {
  name: 'ionic-cache'
};

// pre-cache our key assets
self.toolbox.precache(
  [
    './build/main.js',
    './build/vendor.js',
    './build/main.css',
    './build/polyfills.js',
    './assets/js/d3.min.js',
    './assets/js/jquery.min.js',
    './assets/js/particles.js',
    './assets/js/ripple.min.js',
    './assets/css/animate.min.css',
    './assets/css/ripple.min.css',
    './assets/icon/hypem.png',
    './assets/icon/soundcloud.png',
    './assets/images/placeholder.png',
    './assets/particles.json',
    'index.html',
    'manifest.json'
  ]
);

// dynamically cache any other local assets
self.toolbox.router.any('/*', self.toolbox.cacheFirst);

// for any other requests go to the network, cache,
// and then only use that cached resource if your user goes offline
self.toolbox.router.default = self.toolbox.networkFirst;

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

var messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

tokenProvider.js

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';

declare let window;

@Injectable()
export class TokenProvider {
  public token: string;
  public permissionRequested: boolean = false;
  private user: any;
  private messaging;
  private signedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(private firebaseCordova: Firebase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      if (!user) {
        this.signedIn = false;
        if (!!window.cordova) {
          this.firebaseCordova.onTokenRefresh().subscribe().unsubscribe();
        }
        return;
      }
      this.signedIn = true;
      if (!!window.cordova) {
        this.getToken();
        this.monitorToken();
      } else {
        this.messaging = firebase.messaging();
        this.registerServiceWorker();
      }
    });
  }

  requestPermission() {
    if (!this.permissionRequested) {
      if (!window.cordva) {
        this.messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
          this.getToken();
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', error);
        });
      }
    }
    this.permissionRequested = true;
  }

  registerServiceWorker() {
    if (!!window.swRegistration) {
      this.messaging.useServiceWorker(window.swRegistration);
      this.getToken();
      this.monitorToken();
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.registerServiceWorker();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  getToken() {
    if (!!window.cordova) {
      this.firebaseCordova.getToken().then(token => {
        this.saveToken(token);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error getting token', error);
      });
    } else {
      this.messaging.getToken().then((token) => {
        this.saveToken(token);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', error);
      });
    }
  }

  monitorToken() {
    if (!!window.cordova) {
      this.firebaseCordova.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
        this.saveToken(token);
      });
    } else {
      this.messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
        console.log('Token refreshed');
        this.getToken();
      });
    }
  }

  saveToken(token) {
    if (this.signedIn) {
      console.log('Saving token', token);
      this.token = token;
      const userRef = this.db.object('users/' + this.user.uid);
      userRef.update({
        token: token
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I can successfully generate tokens but when I go into Firebase's message sender and drop in the token in a device-specific notification I never get the response in the browser running the app.

Any ideas? The one weird thing I'm doing is setting window.swRegistration = registration in index.html to pass the value to the tokenProvider.js.

Comment: Do you see anything in console?

Comment: I found out that I can get it working if I send the push notification using fetch or curl. The Firebase admin console only allows you to send to Android/iPhone I think